# Pagination show same page WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I have a custom static frontpage that show recent blogg updates.

But I cant seem to figure out why the pagination doesn't work? I gives me only the link to previous page but when I click the link it just shows the same page but the url changes from
www.homepage.com

to www.homepage.com/page/2

this is my loop.

```
<?php query_posts('posts_per_page=2&category=blogg'); ?>  <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php if (  (function_exists('has_post_thumbnail')) && (has_post_thumbnail())  ) : /* if post has post thumbnail */ ?>
<div class="image"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('archive-preview'); ?></a></div>
<?php endif; ?>


<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?>





<?php endwhile; ?>




<br/>
<?php if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) { wp_pagenavi(); } else { ?>
<?php next_posts_link(__('&larr; Older Entries', 'framework')) ?>
<?php previous_posts_link(__('Newer Entries &rarr;', 'framework')) ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

lease use the code it will help you:

```
 <?php 
if ( get_query_var('paged') ) { $paged = get_query_var('paged'); }
elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) { $paged = get_query_var('page'); }
else { $paged = 1; }

query_posts('posts_per_page=3&paged=' . $paged); 
?>
```

[wordpress codex pagination](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination)